# Let $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ be a function and $S$ a subset of $A$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, solution-verification, elementary-functions

Let $f \colon A \rightarrow B$ be a function and $S$ a subset of $A$.

Are the following containments always valid?.

$(1)    f^{-1} (f(S))⊆ S$

$(2)     S⊆f^{-1} (f(S))$

**Attempt**

$S ⊆ A$

$f^{-1}(S) = \{a ∈ B : f(a) ∈ S\}$

$ a ∈ f^{-1}(S) ⟺ f(a) ∈ S$

$ f^{-1}(S) ⊆ B$

I just need a little help finishing the proof. Am i wrong in the attempt? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what $B$ is

Comment: Sorry! Its A to B.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your proof. $f^{-1}(S)$ doesn't exist. This is because $S$ is a subset of $A$. It only makes sense to take a preimage under $f$ of a subset of $B$. On the other hand, $f(S)$ makes perfect sense. Indeed, $f(S)=\{f(a)\in B|a\in A\}$. Note that $f(S)$ is a subset of $B$. Then, it now makes sense to write $f^{-1}(f(S))=\{a\in A|f(a)\in f(S)\}$. From this it should now be clear that only one of the two options you presented in your question is always true. Can you tell which one it is?

On the other hand, the other option will be true if we add a further assumption on $f$. Can you tell which assumption we need to add? (hint: recall the notion of an injective/surjective function).

Answer (score -1):

Recall that for a function $ f: X \rightarrow Y $, and two subsets $A\subseteq X, B\subseteq Y$ that

$$ (f \circ f^{-1})(B) = I_Y(B)=B \\ (f^{-1} \circ f)(A) = I_X(A)=A $$

Where $I_X, I_Y$ are the identity functions. Do you think you can continue from here?

Comment: The question does not assume that $f$ is invertible. Namely, $f^{-1}$ as a function $f^{-1}:B\rightarrow A$ does not need to exist. In here $f^{-1}$ is used as the notion of a preimage. Namely, if $C$ is a subset of $B$, then $f^{-1}(C)$ is defined as the set of all elements $a\in A$ such that $f(a)\in C$.

Comment: The notation "$f^{-1}$" means the inverse of $f$. If you would like a different function that is $ B \rightarrow A$, than you would have to define it with a different name (like $g: B\rightarrow A$). If $f^{-1}$ is not the inverse of $f$, than simply this question was written badly.

Comment: The notation "$f^{-1}$" for preimage instead of for inverse is standard. See for example https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/preimage or https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Preimage.html. Mind you that $f^{-1}$ understood as the notion of preimage is valid for all functions. For a general $b\in B$ the set $f^{-1}(b)$ can be empty or contain more than one element. In the case $f$ is invertible however $f^{-1}(b)$ will always be of the form $\{a\}$ for some $a\in A$. Then $f^{-1}$ defines a function, namely the inverse of $f$, by $f^{-1}(b)=a$.

Comment: This youtube video seems to get the point across https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBqc8zaOzU4